# How to set focus in listview item?

Tags: android, listview, focus

[image]I have to set focus on listview item. ListView consist of TextView.
point where i want to set focus on listview item, at that point i have the position of that item.

I have tried setSelectio(pos), where pos is the position of listview item, but this results in setting the position of item at position  on the top of the screen.

please suggest me how to proceed.

```
   builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.save,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.d("@gaurav", "changeText is not null");

                        if (null != changeText) {
                            Log.d("@gaurav", "changeText is not null");
                            if (!(changeText.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                                myList
                                        .set(pos, changeText.getText()
                                                .toString());
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("@gaurav", "changeText is null");
                        }
                        getListView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        getListView().setSelection(pos);
                        getListView().requestFocus();
                    }

                });
```

Comment: can you post the code of how you're calling `setSelection(pos)`

Comment: Why do you want to set the focus on a particular row? Do you want the color selector to change, is there an EditText in the layout that you want to have focus?

Comment: i have edited the question, please see the scenario part for better understanding of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to highlight a particular list item based on your requirement. So you are not able to set the focus if the item is not visible in the screen. Am I right ? If that is your problem you can use following method `public void smoothScrollToPosition (int position)
Added in API level 8`  to scroll to that particular position and then use setSelection() method

Comment: You are partially correct. yes i do want to highlight the item in the list view, but that item is and will be visible in screen in every case. So its just matter of highlighting the item. eg as in snapshot, since Sit was selected in listview so after clicking Save or Reset, Sit in listview should be highlighted. but now set selection(pos) is causing the Sit to move on top of screen

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set focus/color on particular index of `ListView`, you should try this, it works well.

```
list.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        list.setSelected(true);
        list.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        list.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        firstListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition +1;
        Log.v("firstListItemPosition", "firstListItemPosition ");
    }                   
});


firstListItemPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```