# How to make 1st item focus in ListView by default whenever enter the list View screen?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-drawable, android-selector

In my list View ,i have to make 1st item to be focused.In my app i have done  D-PAD implementation,If i found the initial focus ,i will navigate the focus by using D-PAD.
  i tried with `setSelection(position)` this code is not working.

I found some strange behaviour of listview,by default it always focus -1 position.I dont know why?,please clarify this behaviour.

My list view items are get load from server.So,when i have to make setSelection() and how to check the setAdpter task completed or not?.

```
@Override
    public final View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_faq, parent,
                false);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.faqlist_text);
        textView.setText("text");
        textView.setMaxLines(2);
        textView.setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        return rowView;
    }
```

adapter.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_list_item" //this is selector
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/cc_question_mark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/faqlist_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest any idea to make 1st item Focus.

Comment: by 1st item you mean 1st row in the listview?

Answer (score 3):

Is your `yourListView` `focusable`?

Do in `onResume()`

```
    yourListView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourListView.setSelection(0);
        yourListView.getChildAt(0).requestFocus()
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    onListItemClick(listView, findViewById(android.R.id.content), 1, 0);
}

public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    listView.setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
            : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}
```

Comment: my code  not inheriting list activity,it just with activity

Answer (score 0):

You might need to give a little bit of delay before using set selection.

```
listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(0);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Where have you put the delay ? In onResume ?

Comment: Can you add some more code of the activity ? If it's not working, there's gotta be some other problem.

Comment: Question has been updated please,please update the answer based on that.

Comment: How do you load the data from the server ? Are you using an AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 0):

if you already try `list.setSelection(position)` then try

```
list.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

I hope it works for you. but remember, update this in main thread or ui thread

**UPDATE**

also try this

```
list.setFocusable(true);
list.requestFocus();
```

**UPDATE 1**

When u get all list from data then call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
list.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: tried with setItemChecked(0,true); ,it is not working.

Comment: list.setFocusable(true);
list.requestFocus();  and list.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
list.requestFocus(); trie ,it is not working

Comment: what you trying to do...may be it can done in other way so explain little more

Comment: for example i have two screens,1st screen is have one button and second screen is list view.by clicking 1st screen button it will take to listview from there i have to focus 1st item

Comment: android:background="?android:activatedBackgroundIndicator" set in your item list layout then try list.setItemChecked(0, true);

Comment: Question has been updated please,please update the answer based on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69814/discussion-between-boopathi-and-lokesh).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).performClick();

Answer (score 0):

Could you show me code getview method in Adapter?
I think you set static viewholder in Adapter.
You should delete `if(convertView == null)` condition.
Look like:

```
        // if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.baseadapter_dropdown_layout, null);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(R.layout.baseadapter_dropdown_layout, holder);

        // } else {
        // holder = (ViewHolder) convertView
        // .getTag(R.layout.baseadapter_dropdown_layout);
        // }
```

Comment: Can you remove `android:background="@drawable/sel_list_item"` and replace by:        `listview.setSelector(getWallpaper());
listview.setSelection(0);` in activity.

Comment: If you select row in list, wallpaper of your phone will set background for selector. you will know which row has been selected.

Comment: Do you want highlight item selected ? or Do you want focus view to item selected? Are you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657136/how-to-set-focus-in-listview-item ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `onResume()` go for

```
mListView.setSelection(position);
```

or

```
mListView.setSelection(listview.getAdapter().getCount()-1);
```

also

```
mListView.requestFocus();
```

also try to manage null check before entering hard coded positions.

Answer (score 0):

Use performItemClick. It will call the OnItemClickListener, if it is defined. This works in charm for me.

```
int setPosition = 0; // Your default position. Any value less than your list size.
int ignoreId = 0; // We ignore the row id of the item that was clicked.
yourListView.setItemChecked(setPosition, true);
yourListView.performItemClick(yourListView.getSelectedView(), setPosition,   ignoreId);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use post with listview you can simply use `listView.setSelection(0)` after adding the data into the list

Comment: i have used setselection also,if i give setSelection(10),that 10 th item will be the first item of screen but focus not happened.

Comment: i have mentioned setselection is not working like that so, i need some other way